# Hive Internal Error: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive and facing problem on the very starting step , while executing any query using hive, i am getting the problem -

> FAILED: Hive Internal Error:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException(java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException:
>   Authentication failed, status: 503, message: Service Unavailable)
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException:
>   Authentication failed, status: 503, message: Service Unavailable

[image]

Comment: I use HDP and restart it. Then, I encounter this error as well.

Answer (score -1):

The Exception is happening due to Authentication not applied for the User which creating the Database for MetaStore Service.

So will suggest to recheck/configure you metastore db.

Sample For MySQL:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'hive'@'metastorehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
...
mysql> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'hive'@'metastorehost';
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,LOCK TABLES,EXECUTE ON metastore.* TO 'hive'@'metastorehost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit;
```

Check the URL for more details:
URL[Link Of Cludera Metastore Configuration](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)